# Python bytes to geojson Point

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, geojson

I have a MySQL database where I have Point type location data and a Django (Django Rest Framework) backend where I am trying to retrieve that data. If I try to get that location data from phpMyAdmin the returned location is something like this `POINT(23.89826 90.267535)`. In my Django backend however, I get a `bytes` as the returned location. The returned value is something like this
`b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x12N\x0b^\xf4\xe57@C\xe2\x1eK\x1f\x91V@'`

The database uses `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation.

If I try to convert the returned bytes to a string with `.decode('utf-8')` I get `UnicodeDecodeError`

```
>>> s = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x12N\x0b^\xf4\xe57@C\xe2\x1eK\x1f\x91V@'
>>> s.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 13: invalid continuation byte
```

I get the same bytes array even if I perform a raw query from Django with the MySQL function `St_AsGeoJson(location)`.

I then tried geojson. When I feed that bytes to `geojson.Point()` I get a geojson back but instead of 2 floats the `coordinates` array consists 25 integer values.

```
>>> s = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x12N\x0b^\xf4\xe57@C\xe2\x1eK\x1f\x91V@'
>>> geojson.Point(s)
{"coordinates": [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 18, 78, 11, 94, 244, 229, 55, 64, 67, 226, 30, 75, 31, 145, 86, 64], "type": "Point"}
```

How can I retrieve the Point data from the bytes or this geojson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem because I was using plain Django and Django models doesn't have a field type that deals with Geo data. I was using a `CharField` with a `max_length=255` and then tried to parse whatever that `CharField` retrieved from the database. I have solved the problem by using GeoDjango and Django REST Framework GIS. Django REST Framework GIS is not necessary. I used it because I am using Django REST Framework and it outputs the Geo data in a nice format.

**Steps were to**

1. Install GDAL(Geospatial Data Abstraction Library)

   `sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
   sudo apt-get install python3-gdal`
2. Add `django.contrib.gis` and `rest_framework_gis` to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`
3. Set `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` in `settings`, in my case it's `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.getenv('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')`
4. Update model import from `from django.db import models` to `from django.contrib.gis.db import models`
5. Update the model to use a Geo field. More: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/

**Links**

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/
- https://github.com/djangonauts/django-rest-framework-gis
- https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki/How-to-install-GDAL